# for文で最後の数値(+1)しか表示されない

Tags: c#

C#で
１から４までの数字を表示するプログラム↓を作ったのですが

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a;
            for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) ;
                Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

コンソールに
5
としか出てきません
いろいろ調べましたが間違いが分かりません
どこが違うのでしょうか

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`for`ステートメントの末尾の`;`が余計です。

> for (a = 0; a < 5; a++) ;
>   Console.WriteLine(a);

これは

```
for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
}
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

と等価です。

この手のミスは「for (**int** a = 0; a < 5; a++)」と`for`内で変数を宣言することで防ぐことができます。

Answer (score 1):

for文に限った話ではないですが、ミスを防ぐためにfor文で行う処理を **{ }** で括ることを推奨します。
また、特定区間の繰り返し処理を行う場合はEnumerable.Rangeメソッドを活用したforeach文を使用するとセミコロンを使う回数が減り、タイプしやすくなるかとは思います。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace experiment2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach(int Looping in Enumerable.Range(1, 4))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Looping);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

> 出力結果
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4

---

> メソッド : System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(int start,int count)について
>   第1引数が開始する値で第2引数は用意される要素数です。
>   コードサンプルの場合だと1,2,3,4が格納されています。
>   このメソッドはint型を格納するIEnumerableを返すため、LINQについて理解を進めることで特殊なパターンを持つループ文の作成も可能になります。